# How to resize the image output for htmlOutput for R Shiny?

Tags: r

I am trying to display the image on Shiny, however, the rendered image ends up being too large (dimensions). How to resize the image output for htmlOutput for R Shiny?

ui

```
sidebarPanel(htmlOutput("picture")
```

server

```
src = "https://storage.googleapis.com/sentinel-nft/raw-assets/fdd20b71b6d497bf1cf5915c8e50e3e381c0d76189b0dbb931b1edbbe79331ae.png"

output$picture<-renderText({c('<img src="',src,'">')})
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23702669/change-size-of-image-with-a-slider-in-shiny.  Basically use renderUI and UIOutput instead of renderText.